# Argparse eats arbitrary strings in the middle of `choice` arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a program that must accept a command line like this:

`python wood.py clean and paint chair red`

The command line reads like this, in this order:

- At least one operation from finite set: `clean`, `sand` or `paint`. The word `and` is for syntax sugar and ignored later
- An single arbitrary furniture name
- A single choice from a finite set of colors: `blue`, `white` or `red`
- An single optional handling option from a finite set: `vintage`,`rush` or `eco`

I've implemented it with the following Python code

```
import argparse

from pprint import pprint as pp

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('operations', metavar='operations', type=str, choices=['clean','sand','paint', 'and'], nargs="+")
parser.add_argument('furniture', metavar='furniture', type=str)
parser.add_argument('color', metavar='color', choices=['blue','white','red'], type=str)
parser.add_argument('handling', metavar='handling', type=str, choices=['rush','vintage','ecologic'], nargs="?")

args = parser.parse_args()

pp([op for op in args.operations if op != 'and'])
pp(args.furniture)
pp(args.color)
pp(args.handling)
```

It works, but when I add the optionnal `handling` parameter at the end, argparse interprets the furniture (chair) as an operation.

```
> python wood.py clean and sand and paint chair red vintage
usage: wood.py [-h]
                  operations [operations ...] furniture [furniture ...] color
                  [handling]
wood.py: error: argument operations: invalid choice: 'chair' (choose from 'clean', 'sand', 'paint', 'and')
```

What makes argparse thinks the arbitrary string after a choice argument is part of that choice?

Comment: It is allocating strings to arguments strictly on position, not value.  Choices checking comes after allocation. `handling` is happy with 0 strings, so `operations` gets everything that isn't needed for the other two.

Comment: It would be better to parse `sys.argv` yourself.  You'll have more control.  Here you are too dependent on the `argparse` details which aren't optimized for this layout.

Comment: It would be better to make `handling` a flagged argument.  That clearly identifies which string applies to that argument.  Having more than one '*+?' `nargs` often causes problems, since each of those is 'greedy'.

Comment: @hpaulj Your comment "[argparse] is allocating strings to arguments strictly on position" is the right answer, post it and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` is confused, because handling starts with `h` and `h` is used for `help`. Use another word or use the uppercase `H`

```
    parser.add_argument('Handling', metavar='handling', help='bam')
```

You will have to use `args.Handling` later since `metavar` only changes the name in help texts.

Comment: Well, not on Python 2.7 anyway. I replaced `handling` with `zzz` and I get the same error.

Comment: Tested in python 2.7 btw.

Comment: Paste full code (I already provided a smal reproducable piece). I still get the error when I replace `handling` with `zzz` : usage: argtest.py [-h] operations [operations ...] furniture color [zzz]

Comment: `help` flag is '-h'.  Position strings are not parsed by value.